# 英語が残っている: 質問の編集ページ「We welcome all constructive edits...」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

他人の質問を編集する際に表示されるページの上部に英語が残っている（以下）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

英語：

> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary.

適当な和訳：

> 積極的な編集は歓迎ですが、意味のある編集にしてください。本当に必要な場合を除いて、ささいな修正は控えてください

Comment: 以下、和訳案です。
「積極的な編集は歓迎ですが、意味のある編集にしてください。本当に必要な場合を除いて、ささいな修正は控えてください」

Comment: @tomute, 適用しました。

Comment: 修正されていることを確認しました。